# OpenCV - Detect rough, hand-drawn circles with obstructions

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, contour

I've been trying to extract hand-drawn circles from a document for a while now but every attempt I make doesn't have the level of consistency I need.

[Process Album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqHjX.jpg)

The problem I keep coming up against is when 2 "circles" are too close they become a single contour, ruining my attempt to detect if a contour is curved. I'm sure there must be a better way to extract these circles, but their imperfection and inconsistency are really stumping me.

I've tried many other ways to single out the curves, the most accurate of which being:

Rather than use dilation to bridge the gap between the segmented contours, find the endpoints and attempt to continue the curve until it hits another  contour.
*Problem: I can't effectively find the turning points of the contour, otherwise this would be my preferable method*

I apologize if this question is deemed "too specific", but I feel like Computer Vision stuff like this can always be applied elsewhere.

Thanks ahead of time for any and all help, I'm about at the end of my rope here.

EDIT: I've just realized the album wasn't working correctly, I think it should be fixed now though.

Comment: If i were you I would just run an object detector and train it to box up the circle shapes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a very challenging problem so it is very likely that the things I am going to write wouldn't work very well in practice.

In order to ease the problem, I would probably try to remove as much of other stuff from the image as possible.

If the template of the document is always the same, it might be worth trying to remove horizontal and vertical lines along with grayed areas. For example, given the empty template, substract it from the document that you are processing. Probably, it might be possible to get rid of the text also. This would result in an image with only parts of hand drawn circles.

On such image, detecting circles or ellipses with hough transform might give some results (although shapes might be far from circles or ellipses).

Comment: Right, sorry, I forgot to mention it in my question, but these results are already after subtracting the base form from this one, however for some reason the documents change in resolution causing them to not line up correctly. The results on that part of the process are consistent enough though. If this seems to be the best way to go about it, the main problem i'm having is contours becoming connected due to dilation. So I need to find a way to connect relevant contours without dilation or a way to detect if 2 "circles" have merged into one contour.